# save images using paperclip without view

Tags: paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to save images from my current local app directory. I have used two models to save images.

business.rb

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
# Associations
   has_attached_file :logo, :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"}
   validates_attachment :logo,
                   :size => {:in => 1..1500.kilobytes}
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :thumb => '100x100>', :medium => '240x240>' }
end
```

when i try to save image it is not working for me like below.

```
Business.create(:logo => Image.first.url)
```

and i have this error

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "/system/images/data/000/000/177/medium/error.png"
```

while "Image.first.url" give me this path

```
   "/system/images/data/000/000/177/medium/error.png"
```

How i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a String(url of first image) to `logo`, try reading image content for url and assign it to logo.Try this!

```
image = open(Image.first.url).read
Business.create(logo: image)
```